# Can't link CSS file to HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm new here, and new to HTML and CSS. I'm trying to learn the different styles of borders that can be created in CSS, but when I try and link the CSS file to the HTML, no borders appear when the HTML is executed in the web browser. Can anyone help? Cheers!

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Border Styles</title>
        <link href="/Users/leighton_blackburn/Documents/HTML/CSS/Border Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>  
        <p class="one"> Hello </p>
        <p class="two"> Hello </p>
        <p class="three"> Hello </p>
        <p class="four"> Hello </p>
        <p class="five"> Hello </p>
        <p class="six"> Hello </p>
        <p class="seven"> Hello </p>
        <p class="eight"> Helo </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
p.one {border-style: solid;}
p.two {border-style: dotted;}
p.three {border-style: dashed;}
p.four {border-style: double;}
p.five {border-style: groove;}
p.six {border-style: ridge;}
p.seven {border-style: inset;}
p.eight {border-style: outset;}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Voting to close as typo/no repro.

Answer (score 1):

There is a whitespace in the link to your css file. Replace it with %20 like so

```
/Users/leighton_blackburn/Documents/HTML/CSS/Border%20Style.css
```

Comment: The answer is perfectly fine, but maybe it's better to create files without spaces for web development in the first place...

Comment: Browsers will error correct that, it shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: You're both right. And Quentin's answer addresses the real problem, the whitespace  can be corrected but doesn't have to. I just saw that.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem sorted itself somehow. Cheers for the tip Michael.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what the `border-style` is if the `border-width` is `0` (which is the default). You need to set that as well.

Add `p { border-width: 4px; }` (for example).

Comment: Cheers! Just opened the HTML file again, and for some reason, it's working perfectly fine now. I'll keep in mind what you said, for future reference though. Thanks again!