# How to link CSS to HTML properly

Tags: html, css

[image]

So my CSS link somehow doesn't work. I can't find a problem with it, but the CSS is not connecting to the HTML. My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

Comment: it will be like this `href="../css/styles.css"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't link CSS file to HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776578/cant-link-css-file-to-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Using your CSS like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

Because your `style.css` is in a folder named CSS and your HTML is in another folder
So you have to use `../` to go back one file directory and go to `css/style.css`
Then the css will be loaded and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the parent folder before being able to access the `css` folder from your html file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on specifics of your project, the CSS subdir could be placed inside the root DIR, along with .html files. Then your `<link>` tag, as shown in question, would take effect.